# Does the succesion of two radical extensions yield a radical extension only in the obvious case?

Tags: polynomials, galois-theory, cyclotomic-polynomials

Answering that recent [stackoverflow question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/577622/kummer-extensions/584336#584336), I encountered the following
related problem :

Let $n,m,p\geq 2$ be integers, and let $K$ be a subfield
 of $\mathbb C$ containing all $nmp$-th roots of unity.

Consider a radical extension $K(a)$ of $K$ with degree $n$, so that
 $a^n\in K$ (and $X^n-a^n$ is irreducible over $K$).
 Consider also a radical extension $K(a)(b)$ of $K(a)$ with degree $m$, so that
 $b^m\in K(a)$ (and $X^m-b^m$ is irreducible over $K(a)$).

Of course, the extension $K(b)/K$ is not radical in general. It will be, however,
 if $b^m$ is a monomial in $a$, $b^m=ca^i$ with $c\in K, i\in{\mathbb N}$. 
 Is the converse also true ? If $K(b)/K$ is radical, must $b^m$ be a monomial
 in $a$ ?

Perhaps this is a “stupid”, very easy question for Kummer theorists.

Comment: Although mathematics tends to become (too) specialized, Kummer theorists are probably a very select group. But of course, for them I guess the question *would* be very easy indeed :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is true.  If $K(b)/K$ is radical then $b^{mn}\in K$, so $b^{mn}$ is fixed by any generator $\sigma$ of $\text{Gal}(K(a)/K)$.  Since $b^m\in K(a)$, it follows that $\sigma(b^m)=\gamma b^m$ where $\gamma^n=1$.  Pick a primitive $n$-th root of unity $\zeta$, and let $\sigma$ be the automorphism of $K(a)$ which fixes every element of $K$ and maps $a\mapsto \zeta a$.
Since $b^m\in K(a)$, we can write
$$
b^m = c_{n-1} a^{n-1} + c_{n-2} a^{n-2} + ... + c_0
$$
with every $c_i\in K$.
Now we compute
$$
\sigma(b^m) = c_{n-1} \sigma(a)^{n-1} + c_{n-2} \sigma(a)^{n-2} + ... + c_0
= c_{n-1} \zeta{n-1} a^{n-1} + c_{n-2}\zeta^{n-2} a^{n-2} + ... + c_0,
$$
so that if $\sigma(b^m)=\gamma b^m$ with $\gamma\in K$ then for each $i$ with $0\le i\le n-1$ we must have $c_i\zeta^i a_i = \gamma c_i a^i$, whence either $c_i=0$ or $\gamma=\zeta^i$.  Since $\zeta^0,\zeta^1,\dots,\zeta^{n-1}$ are pairwise distinct, it follows that $c_i$ is nonzero for at most one value $i$.  Therefore $\sigma(b^m)=c_i a^i$ for some $i$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I deleted the MO version as you suggested